# What's the quickest way to make sprite sheets

Tags: spritesheet

We are only a team of three people and between us we don't really have that much spare time, we only do game development as a hobby.

What would be the most efficient way to make sprite sheets for use with programs such as game maker. 
Just basic movement and actions.

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. Do you need to generate sprite-sheets from existing images/animations? Or do you need help creating the animations in the first place? Your question could use some clarification in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to make sprite sheets is to use pre-existing sprite sheets. You'll find an extensive list of pre-made sprite sheets [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sprite%20sheets&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch) (always consult a lawyer and ask the copyright holders for permission when using content found on the internet)

Here are some other ways to efficiently make sprite sheets:

- Limit your sprites to simple shapes only (squares, circles, etc.)
- Constrain your sprites to 1 - 8 pixels
- Hire an artist to make sprites
- Make friends with an artist and get them to make sprites for free
- Modify the sprite sheets found in the above link to fit your purposes